# Solr: Query for documents whose from-to date range contains the user input

Tags: date, solr, lucene

I would like to store and query documents that contain a from-to date range, where the range represents an interval when the document has been valid.

Typical use cases in lucene/solr documentation address the opposite problem: Querying for documents that contain a single timestamp and this timestamp is contained in a date range provided as query parameter. (createdate:[1976-03-06T23:59:59.999Z TO *])

I want to use the edismax parser.

I have found the ms() function, which seems to me to be designed for boosting score only, not to eliminate non-matching results entirely.

I have found the article [Spatial Search Tricks for People Who Don't Have Spatial Data](https://people.apache.org/~hossman/spatial-for-non-spatial-meetup-20130117/), where the problem described by me is said to be Easy... (Find People Alive On May 25, 1977).

Is there any simpler way to express something like

date_from_query:[valid_from_field TO valid_to_field] than using the spacial approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most direct approach is to create the bounds yourself:

```
valid_from_field:[* TO date_from_query] AND valid_to_field:[date_from_query TO *]
```

.. which would give you documents where the `valid_from_field` is earlier than the date you're querying, and the `valid_to_field` is later than the date you're querying, in effect, extracting the interval contained between `valid_from_field` and `valid_to_field`. This assumes that neither field is multi valued.

I'd probably add it as a filter query, since you don't need any scoring from it, and you probably want to allow other search queries at the same time.